# "string difference " - how to remove a certain substring from a string obtaining the rest

Tags: python, string, strip

If you had two strings,

```
string1 = "Rahul 123 Mumbai Shivani 234 Mumbai Akash 345 Mumbai Rahul 456 Bangalore"

string2 = "Rahul 123 Mumbai"
```

How do you find out the difference?

As in, the final output should be -

```
"Shivani 234 Mumbai Akash 345 Mumbai Rahul 456 Bangalore"
```

I tried using `str.strip()`, but it's giving me incorrect answers.

Comment: That output is not the intersection of the strings.

Comment: I need that output though, what is the operation called then?

Comment: Your question is still ambiguous but you might just be looking for `string1.replace(string2, '').strip()` or maybe `string1.strip(string2)`

Answer (score 2):

You could try

```
string1.replace(string2, '').strip()
```